# wso2IS login issue after configuring with external LDAP server

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have installed WSO2 identity server 5.3.0 in our system and tried to establish external LDAP connection using steps provided by LABKIT.pdf.
I have successfully configured "apache directory studio" on my windows server 20008 R2 Stand. To communicate or authenticate to  "Active Directory"  using Bind DN and password

```
Bind DN       : CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=orap,DC=co,DC=in
Bind Password : Psas@2017!!
```

after configuring necessary settings in a file "user-mgt.xml" for external LDAP settings.Then restarting services  "./wso2servr.sh" shows embedded LDAP settings disabled and External  LDAP connection successful, but login page of WSO2 can't able to log in using

1. default admin login
2. LDAP  Username and password.

How to solve this issue in order to communicate our own LDAP server to WSO2 IS?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your question it seems you haven't added the admin user or pointed an existing admin user for the Identity Server. You can do this via `<AddAdmin>true</AddAdmin>` and adding a new admin user with new password in the user-mgt.xml. Or else you can point existing user in you LDAP server as an admin user in the `<AdminUser>` section in the user-mgt.xml

Answer (score -1):

You need to setup your external LDAP connection as a secondary store. What you define in 'user-mgt.xml' becomes your primary store. Your primary store should be a JDBC store in this instance since you're disabling embedded LDAP. If you do it this way, you'll be able to login with your default admin login. Don't forget to disable the admin settings at the top of user-mgt.xml once you start your WSO2 IS for the first time.

Comment: You don't need to have a JDBC userstore as the primary userstore. You can have a JDBC usestore, a LDAP or a AD as your primary userstore.

Comment: I've never been able to get a WSO2 IS instance up and running otherwise. Can you provide a working example config for a WSO2 Identity Server running only a primary LDAP/AD userstore with no JDBC stores?

Comment: A ton. I’ll have to do some testing to post results but I’ve never been able to define a primary LDAP store without a primary/secondary JDBC store. How do you even log in if you don’t have a resource to store the Identity Server admin password?

Comment: What do you mean "if you don’t have a resource to store the Identity Server admin password"? When you do the proper configurations, you can login to the Identity Server with LDAP.

Comment: @MadurangaSiriwardena can you provide an example?

Comment: IS comes with its embedded ldap configured as the userstore by default. If you need to connect to a external ldap, you have to change the ConnectionURL, ConnectionName, ConnectionPassword. And according to configs in your ldap, you will need to change things like UserSearchBase, UserEntryObjectClass, UserNameAttribute, UserNameSearchFilter, GroupSearchBase, GroupEntryObjectClass, GroupNameAttribute etc. For AdminUser section, you have to add a valid user in ldap if you are planing to connect ldap in read-only mode. Otherwise, AddAdmin can be set to true to add the user in AdminUser section.