# Admin can't access WSO2-IS management console after configuring new primary LDAP user store

Tags: wso2, openldap, wso2-identity-server

While using the default WSO2-IS 5.3.0 user store configuration, admin is able to successfully login to managements console. Upon configuring an external LDAP as the primary user store admin is no longer capable of login at mc.

This post is admittedly similar to [wso2IS login issue after configuring with external LDAP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47220199/wso2is-login-issue-after-configuring-with-external-ldap-server)
Unfortunately, my current platform reputation status doesn't allow for comments and subsequent exploration of the given answer. Additionally, said answer stating "Your primary store should be a JDBC store in this instance since you're disabling embedded LDAP" confuses me thoroughly.

I've read external LDAP can be used as the primary user store, and haven't noticed any references to requirements of JDBC for external LDAP. At least, none that I need to change or edit.

Configuration references:

1) https://medium.com/@gdrdabarera/how-to-configure-open-ldap-with-wso2-identity-server-5-4-0-3a76bf240001

2) https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+a+Read-write+LDAP+User+Store

The "ConnectionName" value types vary between the two. Only following the first reference results in the successful launch of wso2-is. During startup messages 1) Embedded LDAP is disabled and 2) LDAP connection created successfully in read-write mode are displayed, so I have some hope.

usr-mgt.xml

```
<UserManager>
<Realm>
    <Configuration>
    <AddAdmin>true</AddAdmin>
        <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
        <AdminUser>
            <UserName>admin</UserName>
            <Password>admin</Password>
        </AdminUser>
        <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
        <Property name="isCascadeDeleteEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="initializeNewClaimManager">true</Property>
        <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
    </Configuration>



    <!-- Following user manager is used by Identity Server (IS) as its default user manager.
         IS will do token replacement when building the product. Therefore do not change the syntax.
         If "kdcEnabled" parameter is true, IS will allow service principle management.
         Thus "ServicePasswordJavaRegEx", "ServiceNameJavaRegEx" properties control the service name format and
         service password formats. In case if user core cache domain is needed to identify uniquely set property
         <Property name="UserCoreCacheIdentifier">domain</Property>
    -->
    <UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager">
        <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
        <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://localhost:389</Property>
        <Property name="ConnectionName">cn=admin,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
        <Property name="ConnectionPassword">admin</Property>
        <Property name="AnonymousBind">false</Property>
        <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
        <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">identityPerson</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(uid=?))</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
        <Property name="DisplayNameAttribute"/>
        <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
        <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
        <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=Groups,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
        <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">groupOfNames</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
        <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
        <Property name="BackLinksEnabled">false</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Username pattern policy violated</Property>
        <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="PasswordJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Password length should be within 5 to 30 characters</Property>
        <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="SCIMEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="IsBulkImportSupported">false</Property>
        <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">false</Property>
        <Property name="PasswordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
        <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
        <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
        <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
        <Property name="kdcEnabled">false</Property>
        <Property name="defaultRealmName">WSO2.ORG</Property>
        <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="ConnectionPoolingEnabled">false</Property>
        <Property name="LDAPConnectionTimeout">5000</Property>
        <Property name="ReadTimeout"/>
        <Property name="RetryAttempts"/>
    </UserStoreManager>

    <AuthorizationManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager">
        <Property name="AdminRoleManagementPermissions">/permission</Property>
        <Property name="AuthorizationCacheEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled">false</Property>
    </AuthorizationManager>
</Realm>
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may have a look into the LDAP (e.g. using JXplorer tool or ldapquery) is there is user admin created with  admin role.

Comment: Yes, the admin user is displayed with either ldapsearch or jxplorer. I can only assume this is the admin which was setup during installation.

This admin is a member of 2 object classes,
simpleSecurityObject and organizationalRole.

Comment: That are classes of your user ldap object. What you need to look for is an "admin" group with its member "admin". That should be created as well. It is not, you have to do it manually (I believe if the admin user already existed, then the group/role was not created and assigned).

Comment: I was under the impression that this admin would be created automatically as <addAdmin> was set to true in usr-mgt.xml. This is why I assumed the existing LDAP admin was the correct one. Thank you for the update. The project has now shifted though and it's no longer using an external LDAP as the primary user store. Only secondary read only external LDAP user stores are used, which doesn't contain the WSO2 admin account. Sorry for the delay, holidays. Thanks again.

Comment: Do you see any error at the login time? and do you have a user with "cn=admin,dc=wso2,dc=org" as the DN in your system?